# cloudfoundry UAA as SAML IDP

Tags: saml, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I know UAA supports using OAuth to SSO into downstream applications.  Has anyone tried to make UAA a SAML IDP - issuing SAML assertions to downstream SAML SP's?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature that is underway.
I believe it will show up no later than Q2/2016, possibly earlier